# Should we increase the number of samples when adding more classes?

Tags: machine-learning, likelihood, multi-class

Assume we are solving a $k$-class classification problem, $k \geq 2$, and we have a trained classifier $\phi$ from a family of generative or discriminative classifiers $\Phi$
minimizing an objective $\ell$. On a held-out set or via cross-validation, it produces a classification report $R$ consisting of one or more evaluated metrics.

If we decide to add more classes to the data (e.g., an *entertainment* topic to the existing *politics*, *economy*, and *sports*) or split one of the classes into two or more
(e.g., the presence of a disease into its severities), should we also add more examples with
the previous classes in order to prevent regressions? If yes, is there any theoretical
justification for this and/or rule of thumb on the number of additional samples per class?

If you believe the question is too general and the answer depends on multiple factors like
$\Phi$, $R$, and $\ell$, then let's assume additionally that we

- have a limited amount of data (say, a couple of thousands of texts and dozens of
  topics);
- train a shallow neural network minimizing the negative log-likelihood loss;
- evaluate weighted $F_1$.